# Custom Window authentication Page Link For Sharepoint Mobile Page?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, mobile

Now a Days I want to use Login Control For Sharepoint Mobile page. But I cant got any referrence site for this. I have been use one link in my custom mobile page and navigation url for this url go to window authentication page.. Is that possible?. pls reply me asap.

Regards, Ravi